# Which is called first, DllMain() or global static object constructor?

Tags: dll, object, static, constructor, global-variables

I am writing a DLL which defines a global static object.

In the object's constructor I am doing some initialization that may or may not succeed.

Is it possible to signal success or failure of the initialization process in DllMain() ? Which of the two is called first ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

MSDN's [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation says:

> If your DLL is linked with the C
>   run-time library (CRT), the entry
>   point provided by the CRT calls the
>   constructors and destructors for
>   global and static C++ objects.
>   Therefore, these restrictions for
>   DllMain also apply to constructors and
>   destructors and any code that is
>   called from them.

Since the code within DllMain may use the static objects, the static objects must be constructed before DllMain is run for DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, and destroyed after it is run for DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.

You can verify this with a simple test exe and test dll.

EXE:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wprintf(L"Main, loading library\n");
    HMODULE h = LoadLibrary(L"Test.dll");

    if (h)
    {
        wprintf(L"Main, freeing library\n");
        FreeLibrary(h);
    }

    wprintf(L"Main, exiting\n");
    return 0;
}
```

DLL:

```
struct Moo
{
    Moo() { wprintf(L"Moo, constructor\n"); }
    ~Moo() { wprintf(L"Moo, destructor\n"); }
};

Moo m;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        wprintf(L"DllMain, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH\n");
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        wprintf(L"DllMain, DLL_THREAD_ATTACH\n");
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        wprintf(L"DllMain, DLL_THREAD_DETACH\n");
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        wprintf(L"DllMain, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH\n");
        break;
    default:
        wprintf(L"DllMain, ????\n");
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Together those will print:

```
Main, loading library
Moo, constructor
DllMain, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH
Main, freeing library
DllMain, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH
Moo, destructor
Main, exiting
```

As you can see, the static object is constructed before `DllMain(...,DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH,...)` and destroyed after `DllMain(...,DLL_PROCESS_DETACH,...)`