# C++11 std::mutex in Visual Studio 2012 deadlock when locked from DllMain()

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2012

I am seeing a deadlock with `std::mutex` when the mutex is locked from `DllMain()` Below is a minimal DLL test case that exhibits the problem for me. My actual code does the mutex locking because it uses member functions that are also usable outside initialization during normal function.

I think that the problem is a deadlock between the scheduler as seen in the call stack of `main()` thread and the other thread (probably) spawned by the scheduler. The deadlock seems to happen before `main()` is actually executed.

I would appreciate any advice as to how to fix/resolve the deadlock.

Simple DLL:

```
static void testFunc()
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    mtx.lock();

    mtx.unlock();
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        testFunc ();
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        testFunc ();
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

At the point of the deadlock there are two threads in the process:

```
Not Flagged >   6408    0   Main Thread Main Thread msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::SchedulerBase    Normal
Not Flagged     7600    0   Worker Thread   ntdll.dll!_TppWaiterpThread@4() ntdll.dll!_NtDelayExecution@8   Normal
```

Here is the call stack of `main()` thread:

```
    ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForKeyedEvent@16() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_TppWaitpSet@16() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_TppSetWaitInterrupt@12() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_RtlRegisterWait@24() Unknown
    kernel32.dll!_RegisterWaitForSingleObject@24()  Unknown
>   msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::SchedulerBase(const Concurrency::SchedulerPolicy & policy) Line 152  C++
    msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::ThreadScheduler::ThreadScheduler(const Concurrency::SchedulerPolicy & policy) Line 26   C++
    msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::ThreadScheduler::Create(const Concurrency::SchedulerPolicy & policy) Line 34    C++
    msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::CreateWithoutInitializing(const Concurrency::SchedulerPolicy & policy) Line 276  C++
    msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::GetDefaultScheduler() Line 650   C++
    msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::CreateContextFromDefaultScheduler() Line 567 C++
    msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::SchedulerBase::CurrentContext() Line 399    C++
    msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::details::LockQueueNode::LockQueueNode(unsigned int timeout) Line 616 C++
    msvcr110d.dll!Concurrency::critical_section::lock() Line 1017   C++
    msvcp110d.dll!mtx_do_lock(_Mtx_internal_imp_t * * mtx, const xtime * target) Line 65    C++
    msvcp110d.dll!_Mtx_lock(_Mtx_internal_imp_t * * mtx) Line 144   C++
    ConsoleApplicationDll.dll!std::_Mtx_lockX(_Mtx_internal_imp_t * * _Mtx) Line 68 C++
    ConsoleApplicationDll.dll!std::_Mutex_base::lock() Line 43  C++
    ConsoleApplicationDll.dll!testFunc() Line 16    C++
    ConsoleApplicationDll.dll!DllMain(HINSTANCE__ * hModule, unsigned long ul_reason_for_call, void * lpReserved) Line 29   C++
    ConsoleApplicationDll.dll!__DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved) Line 508    C
    ConsoleApplicationDll.dll!_DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved) Line 472 C
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpCallInitRoutine@16() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpRunInitializeRoutines@4()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitializeProcess@8()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__LdrpInitialize@8()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_LdrInitializeThunk@8()   Unknown
```

The second thread's call stack is short:

```
>   ntdll.dll!_NtDelayExecution@8() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__LdrpInitialize@8()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_LdrInitializeThunk@8()   Unknown
```

**EDIT 1:**

WinDbg confirms that it is loader lock issue:

```
PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_HANG_HungIn_LoaderLock
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2009/12/03/dont-do-anything-in-dllmain-please/) can help?

Comment: The second threads call stack looks somewhat incomplete, if both somehow deadlocked, I would expect at least some functions that access the mutex in there...

Comment: @AndyProwl: I will accept your answer if you tell me how to reliably initialize DLL's state then without using `DllMain()`. :)

Comment: @wilx: That was not an answer :-) I just thought the link might have helped figuring out the root cause of your problem

Comment: from the horse: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx *Because DLL notifications are serialized, entry-point functions should not attempt to communicate with other threads or processes. Deadlocks may occur as a result.* and *Calling functions that require DLLs other than Kernel32.dll may result in problems that are difficult to diagnose.*

Comment: @wilx, export an `init()` function from the DLL and invoke it. Another useful document can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx

Comment: wilx, can you post the initial part of the execution (i.e. which DLLs have been loaded).  one guess is that you are accessing ntdll which is in the processing of being loaded.  however, it can't be loaded because you're blocking the dll load pipeline with the mutex.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496233/which-is-called-first-dllmain-or-global-static-object-constructor

Comment: It may simply be buggy. I encountered another problem of std::mutex, and I found more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319344/stdmutex-lock-hangs-when-overriding-the-new-operator. I tried your code with boost::mutex, and it works! Maybe you should consider that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using `QueueUserAPC()` to queue initialization is always executed before main() but out of the dreaded loader lock. This looks like a solution to my problem.

**EDIT 1**

After some testing it seems that the APC method works if I queue the APC from `DllMain()` but it does not work if I queue the APC from a ctor of a static global instance of a class. IOW, using the APC is not uniformly usable across all possible combinations of compilers and build modes for me.

Answer (score 5):

Check the [Best Practices for Creating DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx) document:

> You should never perform the following tasks from within DllMain:
>
> - Call LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx (either directly or indirectly). This can cause a deadlock or a crash.
> - Synchronize with other threads. This can cause a deadlock.

Comment: Who's synchronizing with other threads?  I don't see any other threads.

Comment: The point of failure is the mutex, not the other threads. mutex is for synchronizing with other threads.