# Why console app hangs when using a shared dll that containg static variable that use mutex?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2013, dll, shared-libraries

I have a shared dll library that contains a class as below :

inside A.dll >> **Header File :**

```
class API ErrorHandler  
{
public:
    ErrorHandler();

    virtual ~ErrorHandler();
protected:  
    static ErrorHandler* defaultHandler();

private:
    static ErrorHandler* _pHandler;
    static std::mutex     _mutex;
};
```

**source(.cpp)**

```
ErrorHandler* ErrorHandler::_pHandler = ErrorHandler::defaultHandler();
std::mutex ErrorHandler::_mutex;


ErrorHandler::ErrorHandler()
{
}


ErrorHandler::~ErrorHandler()
{
}

ErrorHandler* ErrorHandler::defaultHandler()
{   
    static SingletonHolder<ErrorHandler> sh;
    return sh.get(); **<<====== here we get hanged** see the declaration of get
}
```

**SingletoneHolder header file**

```
template <class S>
class SingletonHolder
{
public:
    SingletonHolder():
        _pS(0)
    {
    }

    ~SingletonHolder()
    {
        delete _pS;
    }

    S* get()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_m); <===== cause thread hang
        if (!_pS) _pS = new S;

        return _pS;
    }

private:
    S* _pS;
    std::mutex _m;
};
```

After building the above code (every thing related to compiler setting configured correctly) now I want to use it in my console app.

After running console app, app hangs and never reach to main function.

Why `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_m);` hangs and prevent main thread to continue executing?

What is alternative?

I am using VS2013 Update5.

content of main file :

```
#include "ErrorHandler" <== when remove this include app run correctly
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me on VS 2013 Update 5 with an empty `main`. You should post the contents of the console app, maybe you are invoking some of the exported class members.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++11 std::mutex in Visual Studio 2012 deadlock when locked from DllMain()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711263/c11-stdmutex-in-visual-studio-2012-deadlock-when-locked-from-dllmain)

Comment: Two mutex objects, I smell a rat.  Post the call stack of the deadlocked thread.

Comment: @Rudolfs Bundulis : DllMain is generated by default. i never use it

Comment: @amir110 I know that it is generated by default. Nevertheless that is where the initialization of static objects take place.

Comment: here :
 ErrorHandler* ErrorHandler::_pHandler = ErrorHandler::defaultHandler();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should post exact contents of the `main` - with an empty `main` everything works. Things go south when the `ErrorHandler` class is being instantiated inside `main`.

Second, the initialization of your static members occurs inside `__DllMainCRTStartup` and as stated in the SO question I marked as duplicate, MSDN states that using synchronization primitives from `__DllMainCRTStartup` can cause a deadlock. A possible solution is to switch to a critical secion.

Comment: first of all , my main function is emty and i only include the ErrorHandler class header file.(when i remove EventHandler header file from include list every thing works fine and i can get break inside main function).

i implement the mutext class using Critical_Section and now every thing works fine

Comment: @amir110 sorry if my wording was incorrect - I mean you must have instantiated the `ErrorHandler` instance somewhere, ok maybe not inside `main` but somewhere, otherwise if you did no have any calls to the dll it would not even be loaded.

Comment: as ErrorHandler class variable declared as static (if you check the code above) it is instantiated when app become live.